# Reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on existing drive partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I am currently dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I had provided ubuntu with a petty 70 gbs and alloted the remaining storage of my 500 gb(i.e around 420 gbs in three partitions) HDD to windows 10, but recently I have been using ubuntu alot, now I think 70 gb is quite small for the usage I have.

So I want to reinstall ubuntu by taking 1 partitions from windows and merging it existing ubuntu partition and then reinstalling. In that way I won't be losing my windows data.

Is there anything I need to take care of before proceeding to this, as I recall I might encounter a problem which will disable my access to windows  into boot/grub menu or vice versa.

How do I avoid such instances?

Comment: To resize Windows partition, is better you use Windows tool (https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh848680(v=wps.630).aspx). After that, boot with live-USB ubuntu and resize your Ubuntu partition to include space left from Windows. It's important these two partitions are contiguous. Reinstall Ubuntu on it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't necessarily have to reinstall Ubuntu to enlarge its partition size. If you can shrink partitions right next to the Ubuntu partition, you can then enlarge it without having to reinstall. I suggest you include a screenshot from GParted.

If you do have partitions right next to the Ubuntu partition, all you need to do is boot from a GParted live USB (instruction [here](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php)). After that, I believe you just have to shrink a partition right next to it by right-clicking and choosing the resize option, and then resize your Ubuntu partition to use up that unallocated space. Remember you can't do it from the GParted of your Ubuntu installation. You will need to boot from a GParted live USB.